# Could not retrieve GUID from Xamarin iOS SecKeychain

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

In my Xamarin iOS app, I am storing the DeviceId and AccessToken in the keychain. For saving and retrieving the access token my code works fine, but for the device id(It is a GUID) on saving the device-id it gives the result as `DuplicateItem`, and on retrieving the device-id it gives the result as `ItemNotFound`. I am using seperate keys for device Id and access token. Here is my code

```
public const string DEVICE_ID = "DEVICE_ID";
public const string ACCESS_TOKEN = "ACCESS_TOKEN";

public static string GetValue(string key)
{
    var query = new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword)
    {
       Generic = NSData.FromString(key)
    };

    SecStatusCode result;
    var match = SecKeyChain.QueryAsRecord(query, out result);
    if (result == SecStatusCode.Success)
    {
       return match.ValueData.ToString();
    }
    return string.Empty;
}

public static void SetValue(string value, string key)
{
    var query = new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword)
    {
       ValueData = NSData.FromString(value),
       Generic = NSData.FromString(key)
    };

    var result = SecKeyChain.Add(query);
}
```

I save and get the device id by the method calls like

```
SetValue(Guid.NewGuid(), DEVICE_ID); 
string deviceId = GetValue(DEVICE_ID);
```

It may look weird but I don't know why it is behaving like this, Does anyone had experienced this issue or Is there any error in my code. Please help me.

Comment: I assume you're not using the same key each time to store it?#

Comment: I am using the same key "deviceid" for storing and retrieving the data

Comment: well you can't use the same key for both the GUID, and the Token... otherwise how would the keychain know which one you're requesting when you come to retrieve them. You have to make sure you are using two different 'keys'

Comment: I am using seperate keys. Sorry for not giving a detailed code, I have updated my code.

Comment: so just to clarify when you're storing your strings (GUID's etc), you are doing:   SetValue(Guid.NewGuid(), ACCESS_TOKEN);  AND SetValue(Guid.NewGuid(), DEVICE_ID);   ?

Comment: Extremely sorry for the typo, It is DEVICE_ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is our class for storing and retrieving from the SecKeyChain, I'd suggest using ours and see if you get the same results.

```
using Security;
using Foundation;

public class KeyChain
{
    public const string DEVICE_ID = "DEVICE_ID";
    public const string ACCESS_TOKEN = "ACCESS_TOKEN";

    public string ValueForKey(string key)
    {
        var record = ExistingRecordForKey (key);
        SecStatusCode resultCode;
        var match = SecKeyChain.QueryAsRecord(record, out resultCode);

        if (resultCode == SecStatusCode.Success)
            return NSString.FromData (match.ValueData, NSStringEncoding.UTF8);
        else
            return String.Empty;
    }

    public void SetValueForKey(string value, string key) 
    {
        var record = ExistingRecordForKey (key);            
        if (value.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            if (!ValueForKey(key).IsNullOrEmpty())
                RemoveRecord(record);

            return;
        }

        // if the key already exists, remove it
        if (!ValueForKey(key).IsNullOrEmpty())
            RemoveRecord(record);

        var result = SecKeyChain.Add(CreateRecordForNewKeyValue(key, value));
        if (result != SecStatusCode.Success)
        {
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Error adding record: {0}", result));
        }
    }

    private SecRecord CreateRecordForNewKeyValue(string key, string value)
    {
        return new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword)
        {
            Account = key,
            Service = ServiceName,
            Label = key,
            ValueData = NSData.FromString(value, NSStringEncoding.UTF8),
        };
    }

    private SecRecord ExistingRecordForKey(string key)
    {
        return new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword)
        {
            Account = key,
            Service = ServiceName,
            Label = key,
        };
    }

    private bool RemoveRecord(SecRecord record)
    {
        var result = SecKeyChain.Remove(record);
        if (result != SecStatusCode.Success)
        {
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Error removing record: {0}", result));
        }

        return true;
    }        
}
```

Then the class and or method that you want to retrieve the information from would look like this:

```
public class OtherClass
{
    Public void GetInfo()
    {
        // Store device id
        KeyChain.SetValueForKey(Guid.NewGuid(), KeyChain.DEVICE_ID);

        // Retrieve device id
        string value = KeyChain.ValueForKey(DEVICE_ID);

        // Store access token
        KeyChain.SetValueForKey(Guid.NewGuid(), KeyChain.ACCESS_TOKEN);

        // Retrie acce token
        string value = KeyChain.ValueForKey(ACCESS_TOKEN);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks and lot, it works fine. Can you say what is the problem with my code?

Comment: @RikudouSennin I think it was just because you weren't using 'var record = ExistingRecordForKey(key);' and passing the record in as the query rather than the key.